# Can i Upgrade SQL server 2008r2 express to sql server 2014 Developer edition

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I currently have SQL server 2008 R2 Express installed for my QA/Dev environment on Amazon EC2 instance.

Now my database is growing beyond the 10GB limitation of Express edition, so am planning to buy SQL server 2014 Developer edition.

So can i **upgrade my SQL Express 2008 R2** to **SQL server 2014 Developer Edition**, if yes what is the procedure?

Comment: You have posted questions in multiple stack forums. Answer is already provided inplace upgrde is not supported only side by side upgrade is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can Upgrade Sql-Server 2008r2 to 2014 developer edition.

First of all restoring backup will not upgrade your database. So,

1) Microsoft SQL Server 2014 installation setup provide options to upgrade your database either from 2008 R2 or from 2012. This will preform all the process and provide information if your database is upgradeable or you required to make some changes to your old database. After that you can proceed to upgrade database from 2008 R2 to 2014.

My recommendation would be to install SQL Server 2014 instance and then backup and migrate database from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014

2) There are other third party tools that will preform all the necessary processes and messaging before upgrade.

You can get complete installation details here :

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3245/quick-guide-to-upgrading-to-sql-server-2014/

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can upgrade. Check this [Upgrades from Earlier Versions to SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx)

Comment: But upgrading will not loose the existing data right

Comment: Upgrading usually doesn't affect any data. But take backups as a safety measure.

Comment: @Appu. Where did you find and where it is writen in BOL that Inplace upgrade from express 2008 R2 to 2012 is supported. I cannot find it anywhere , can you show me

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can upgrade it. You are not written your service pack of sqlserver. Here is the link to what and how to upgrade to Sqlserver2014.

Before doing this type of task always ready for rever, so take backup and restore any other pc.

This will give the whole up-gradation details

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677622.aspx

http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/SQL-Server-upgrade-paths-What-to-do-before-during-after-upgrading

> ```
> SQL Server 2012 SP1
> SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2
> SQL Server 2008 SP3
> SQL Server 2005
> ```

http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2014/migrating-sql-server-2014

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707783.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx

Comment: But upgrading will not loose the existing data right.

Comment: Ajay you must mention that inplace upgrade is not supported